# Matlab: find mode in range

Tags: matlab, mode

I have a matrix like:

```
A=
    10 31 32 22
    32 35 52 77
    68 42 84 32
```

I need a function like `mode` but with range, for example mymode(A,10) that return 30, find most frequent number in range 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, .... and return most number in range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to bin your data into the ranges of your desire and then find the bin with the most members using [`max`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/max.html) on the output of `histc`

```
ranges = 0:10:50;                 % your desired ranges
[n, bins] = histc(A(:), ranges);  % bin the data
[v,i] = max(n);                   % find the bin with most occurrences

[ranges(i) ranges(i+1)]           % edges of the most frequent bin
```

For your specific example this returns

```
ans =

    30    40
```

which matches with your required output, as the most values in A lay between 30 and 40.

Answer (score 1):

```
[M,F] = mode(  A((A>=2) & (A<=5))  ) %//only interested in range 2 to 5
```

...where M will give you the mode and F will give you frequency of occurence

Answer (score 1):

```
> A = [10 31 32 22; 32 35 52 77; 68 42 84 32]
A =

   10   31   32   22
   32   35   52   77
   68   42   84   32

> min = 10
min =  10
> max = 40
max =  40
> mode(A(A >= min & A <= max))
ans =  32
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess by the number of different answers that we may be missing your goal. Here is my interpretation.

If you want to have many ranges and you want to output most frequent number for every range, create a cell containing all desired ranges (they could overlap) and use cellfun to run mode() for every range. You can also create a cell with desired ranges using arrayfun in a similar manner:

```
A = [10 31 32 22; 32 35 52 77; 68 42 84 32];

% create ranges
range_step = 10;
range_start=[0:range_step:40];
range=arrayfun(@(r)([r r+range_step]), range_start, 'UniformOutput', false)

% analyze ranges
o = cellfun(@(r)(mode(A(A>=r(1) & A<=r(2)))), range, 'UniformOutput', false)

o = 
[10]    [10]    [22]    [32]    [42]
```